# 'This' undefined in parsing the xml API using react

Tags: javascript, xml, reactjs, api, this

I have been trying to make a data from `XML` clickable in react. This is working in one of the function but gives an error when it is called in an another function.

> Shows = Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'getAuthArticles' of undefined

I have tried using `bind(this)`. I am already using the arrow functions

```
getData() {
  fetch(`http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=ti:${'therapy'}&sortBy=lastUpdatedDate&sortOrder=ascending`).then(data=>data.text()).then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml")).then(data => {
      var entry = data.getElementsByTagName("entry");
      let elems = []
      for(let i=0;i<entry.length;i++){
        console.log(entry);
        let elem = <div key={i} id={entry[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].textContent} onClick={this.handleChange}>{entry[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].textContent}</div>;
        elems.push(elem);
      }
      console.log(elems)
      this.setState({data: elems});
    })
}
/*  */
handleChange(evt) {
  console.log(evt.target.id)
  var res = evt.target.id.split("/");
  var id = res[5]
  fetch(`http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?id_list=${res[4]}/${id}`)
  .then(data=>data.text()).then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
    .then(data => {
      var summ = data.getElementsByTagName("summary");
      let auth = data.getElementsByTagName("author");
      let elems1 = [];
      let name = [];
      console.log(auth)

      for (let i = 0; i < auth.length; i++ ){
        console.log(auth[i].textContent);
        console.log(auth[i].getElementsByTagName("id"));
        let elem1 = <div key={i} id={auth[i].textContent} onClick={this.getAuthArticles.bind(this)}>{auth[i].textContent}</div>;
        name += auth[i].textContent;
        // elems1.push(elem1);
        // console.log(elem1)
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = summ[0].textContent + name;
      // window.history.pushState({}, "page 2", "bar.html");
      // this.setState({data: elems1});

    })
  }
  getAuthArticles(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.id)
    let auth_name = evt;
    fetch(`http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=${auth_name}`)
    .then(data=> data.text()).then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
      .then(data => {
        var arti = data.getElementsByTagName("title");
        let titles = []
        for(let i=0;i<arti.length;i++){
          let elem = <div key={i} id={arti[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].textContent}>{arti[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].textContent}</div>;
          titles.push(elem);
        }
        console.log(titles)

    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using normal function and you missing `bind(this)` in `getData()`

```
onClick={this.handleChange}

// should change to

onClick={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
```

And make sure you `bind(this)` for `getData()`

It will easier with **arrow** function like

```
handleChange = (evt) => {}
```

you don't need to `bind(this)` for **arrow** function